# In openmp, are local variables in fortran subroutine private by default?

Tags: fortran, openmp, fortran90

A basic doubt on private and shared variables in OpenMP. The code looks something as follows. The array **arr** contains variable from 1 to 10 and it is global.

```
PROGRAM TEST
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: i,j
DO i=1,10
   call check()
END DO
END PROGRAM TEST

SUBROUTINE CHECK()
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: testvar,i
!$OMP PARALLEL DO
DO i = 1,10
   testvar = a(i)-1
   print testvar
END DO
!$END PARALLEL DO
END SUBROUTINE CHECK
```

Question: Is the variable `testvar` which is local to subroutine private by default? A major difference here is that the `!$OMP PARALLEL` starts only inside the subroutine and hence this is not an orphaned directive. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Fortran the *index variable* of a loop is automatically made private. All other variables are *shared*.

If you call a `subroutine` from a parallel region, the *local* variables in that subroutine are also private to the thread.

To answer your question: Although `testvar` is local to the subroutine, it is *shared* for all threads, as the parallel section is located in the subroutine as well. If you moved the parallel section to the main program, and then called the subroutine, this would be different.

Comment: but when i tried to use a variable in a subroutine even without declaring it as private, for example **testvar** in the above example it behaves as if it is private. Why is it so?

Comment: How can you tell? Fill `a` with numbers from one to ten. If `testvar` would really be private, it could never happen that a number is printed twice - but it does!

Comment: it was not printing out for me .. it was printing exactly once. i am not sure whether it is compiler dependent

Comment: It should not be compiler dependent... But it might that the compiler optimizes the loop and merges the two statements (as you do nothing else with `testvar`in the loop). Try it with `-O0`.